# Upload Laravel website on smarterasp.net host

Tags: php, laravel

Uploaded laravel project to hosting show login interface properly
But when you type the username and password and click on login, the error appears as below .

> version laravel : 6.0

the errors are:

> The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.

```
(1/1) LogicException
The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.

in Process.php line 143
at Process->__construct(array(), 'H:\\root\\home\\alwheeb-001\\www\\site1\\myeasiestexchange', null, null, 60.0)
in Process.php line 195
at Process::fromShellCommandline('git log --pretty=format:\'%H\' -n 1', 'H:\\root\\home\\alwheeb-001\\www\\site1\\myeasiestexchange')
in AddGitInformation.php line 51
at AddGitInformation->command('git log --pretty=format:\'%H\' -n 1')
in AddGitInformation.php line 25
at AddGitInformation->hash()
in AddGitInformation.php line 13
at AddGitInformation->handle(object(Report), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Report))
in AddSolutions.php line 28
at AddSolutions->handle(object(Report), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Report))
in AddQueries.php line 22
at AddQueries->handle(object(Report), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Report))
in AddDumps.php line 22
at AddDumps->handle(object(Report), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Report))
in AddLogs.php line 22
at AddLogs->handle(object(Report), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Report))
in AddEnvironmentInformation.php line 20
at AddEnvironmentInformation->handle(object(Report), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Report))
in SetNotifierName.php line 15
at SetNotifierName->handle(object(Report), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Report))
in AnonymizeIp.php line 17
at AnonymizeIp->handle(object(Report), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Report))
in AddGlows.php line 24
at AddGlows->handle(object(Report), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Report))
in Pipeline.php line 105
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Flare.php line 245
at Flare->applyMiddlewareToReport(object(Report))
in Flare.php line 221
at Flare->createReport(object(InvalidArgumentException))
in ErrorPageHandler.php line 39
at ErrorPageHandler->handle(object(InvalidArgumentException))
in IgnitionWhoopsHandler.php line 25
at IgnitionWhoopsHandler->handle(object(InvalidArgumentException))
in Run.php line 321
at Run->handleException(object(InvalidArgumentException))
in Handler.php line 345
at Handler->renderExceptionWithWhoops(object(InvalidArgumentException))
in Handler.php line 324
at Handler->renderExceptionContent(object(InvalidArgumentException))
in Handler.php line 308
at Handler->convertExceptionToResponse(object(InvalidArgumentException))
in Handler.php line 287
at Handler->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(InvalidArgumentException))
in Handler.php line 192
at Handler->render(object(Request), object(InvalidArgumentException))
in Handler.php line 49
at Handler->render(object(Request), object(InvalidArgumentException))
in Pipeline.php line 51
at Pipeline->handleException(object(Request), object(InvalidArgumentException))
in Pipeline.php line 132
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in PreventBackHistory.php line 17
at PreventBackHistory->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Localization.php line 22
at Localization->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 76
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in StartSession.php line 56
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in EncryptCookies.php line 66
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 105
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Router.php line 682
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))
in Router.php line 657
at Router->runRoute(object(Request), object(Route))
in Router.php line 623
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php line 612
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))
in Kernel.php line 176
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 130
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php line 21
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php line 21
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 62
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in TrustProxies.php line 57
at TrustProxies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php line 171
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php line 105
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Kernel.php line 151
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php line 55
```

How can I solve this problem?
And does the hosting support laravel projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of Flare error reporting service enabled in debug mode
There is a workaround for this.

Publish flare config file
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=flare-config`

and in config/flare.php

Set

`'collect_git_information' => false`

```
'reporting' => [
    'anonymize_ips' => true,
    'collect_git_information' => false,
    'report_queries' => true,
    'maximum_number_of_collected_queries' => 200,
    'report_query_bindings' => true,
    'report_view_data' => true,
],
```

---

*Taken from [this comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30054#issuecomment-538468357) in laravel/framework github issue*

Comment: I do that and see this problem  :SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = galal20014@gmail.com limit 1)